# App crashed due to can't find some removed IBOutlet binding on view controller when upgrade app with Xcode

Tags: ios, migration, upgrade, xib, iboutlet

Just want to share my experience to avoid wasting your time with the stupid Xcode.

Recently, we were about to release our v1.3 App, due to some core data changes, we have to do some sqlite DB data migration, in order to test this scenario, I just installed v1.1 app on my device with **iTunes**, and built latest v1.3 code with **Xcode** and ran on my device, after successfully migrated data and code returned from [AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:], app crashed with below error.

```
29:46.880 MyApp[3879:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PGSignInViewController 0x1c5d4840> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key **buttonConnectFacebook**.'
```

Actually, the **buttonConnectFacebook** property and IBOutlet binding has already removed from `PGSignInViewController` since v1.2 during code refactoring, searched in my project, both code and `UIlayout`, found no **buttonConnectFacebook** , it seems there were some cached `UIlayout` on my device or `Xcode`.

So I cleaned my project, rebuild my app and installed latest code on my device, no luck;
Then I tried to reboot my device, no luck;
Reset my device, no luck;
Deleted the entire Xcode derived data folder: `/*****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData ,` still not work.

After 2 days struggle, tried different methods, finally, I tried to upgrade my App as much as similar to user upgrades their app, I archived my v1.3 app and distributed with Ad hoc provision profile, installed v1.1 app with **iTunes**, launched v1.1 app to make sure write some data to sqlite DB, install v1.3 app with **iTunes** , launched v1.3 app... tears, it works without any no crash, everything is fine included migrated data.

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Actually this crash only happens when I upgrade from v1.1 to v1.3, upgrade v1.2 to v1.3 works normally with Xcode.

Comment: My Xcode version is 5.0.1 (5A2053), mac OS X v10.8.5

Answer (score 0):

If you get above issue, tried to simulator how user upgrades their app, install old version with **iTunes** or **Testflight**, install new version with **iTunes** or **Testflight**. It seems Xcode has some bug to deal with this situation.